# How to create a confirm dialog box before submit in Yii framework

Tags: php, yii, yii-components

I'm new to Yii framework, I need to create a confirm dialog to pop up before I submit a form. Below is the code of the form used to approve and reject. I need a pop up to appear before I submit to confirm whether approved or rejected.

```
<div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Approved'); ?>
<?php
 echo $form->radioButtonList($model, 'Approved',
                    array(  1 => 'Approved',
                            0 => 'Rejected',
 ),

                   array(
    'labelOptions'=>array('style'=>'display:inline'), // add this code
    'separator'=>'  ',
) );


?>


        <?php echo $form->error($model,'Approved'); ?>
    </div>
```

**Edit**

```
<div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
    </div>
```

How can I achieve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `htmlOptions` into your `submitButton` like:

```
 <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save',
    array('confirm'=> 'Are you Sure')); ?>
```

It will show a confirm dialog when you click submitButton.

Comment: I want the confirm box to display "Are you sure to approve" or "Are you sure to reject" based on radiobutton

Comment: This uses a javascript alert() popup, which I discourage due to its ability to blocking other javascript execution.

Comment: Not working! Missing 'data' attribute first. See next following post.

Answer (score 4):

```
<?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', [
    'class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary',
    'data' => [
        'confirm' => 'Are you sure want to Create/Update this message?'
        ]
    ]) ?>
```

Use data attribute.